# Times New Roman Font in pdfLatex

Tags: fonts, pdftex, times

I need to set main font of my document using Times New Roman font. But I just found one solution that is to compile document using xelatex. But my document built since first typing using pdflatex, so when I switch the enggine to xelatex there are so many error I found. And I cannot fix that error immediately. So I need to find solution to set a font to Times New Roman in pdfLatex.

Comment: There shouldn't be so many problems. Have you checked: 1) your .tex  file is utf8 encoded; 2) you  don't load the `inputenc` not the `fontenc` packages. Also `not all functionalities of `microtype` are availablewith xelatex`. Finally you'd better load `polyglossia` rather than `babel` since the former is specifically designed for xelatex. That's about all, as far as I know.

Comment: You've already asked a couple of questions about how to load packages that provide Times New Roman fonts under pdfLaTeX. Please be more specific about any problems you're encountering when following the previous suggestions.

Comment: @Bernard Some languages are supported by `babel` but not `polyglossia` so this is not an option for all of us!

Comment: @MohammadFajar With regard to your comment on Mario’s answer: I’m afraid you’re unlikely to find a pdfLaTeX package for a Times font that results in the exact same output as using Times New Roman and XeLaTeX.

Comment: Assuming that you really need Times New Roman, and that Times won't do, there are some instructions at this link: http://spacehorn.com/osx/xtra/tnr.html .  I have not attempted this.  Note that these instructions are for the Mac, so you may need to adjust for your system if different.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using `pdflatex`, you can try setting in your preamble:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
```

Something like this would be a MWE where you'll get times new roman as your font for the whole document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\begin{document}

Hello.  This is in Times New Roman font.

\end{document}
```

Comment: sory but when I compile my document using  mathptmx package, the output was not similar to that in Times News Roman font. I get some suggestion in other post to use package \usepackage{newtxtext} but not exactly similar to Times News Roman

Comment: Perhaps get a closer look at the [`mathptmx` documentation](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathptmx)